# Black screen in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, runtime-error

It's really puzzling but my user reported an error yesterday: there were a whole array of error messages popping up, and *bam!* the Silverlight screen goes black. This happened in Chrome; I'm not able to reproduce it (I don't know how), so it totally gets me...

Has anyone faced this before? is there a way to reproduce it, or resolve it? Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue for me as well. The browser hangs for a second until the silverlight object crashes.

For me the solution was to do the server-calls and loading logic in the Loaded event instead of in the constructor, such as:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
   this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyUserControl_Loaded);
   // this.DoAllBuisnessStuff() should not be here.
}

private void MyUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.DoAllBuisnessStuff();
}
```